# Custom emote reactions appear in the wrong order on some platforms

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I have used regular emojis in my bot for voting for a while, but I recently changed them to custom emojis. The problem is that they now appear in the wrong order, but only on some devices. On my computer, they're in the correct order, but on my phone, they're in a semi-random one.

Correct order (on pc client):

[image: From red to green]

Wrong order (on mobile):

[image: Yellow is at the end]

I've tried introducing some delays between the reactions, but nothing changed.

Code that does the reacting:

```
const ratings = ["579368037761810442", "579368037111693312", "579368036528816158", "579368037682249728", "579368036809834517"];

async function ratabalize(message) {
  for (var i = 0; i < ratings.length; i++) {
    await message.react(ratings[i]);
  }
}
```

Comment: Does this happen on mobile devices only? Does the wrong order change every time or stays the same? Do other users have the same problem when displaying the same message?

Comment: Seems to be mobile only, but ive only tested with one computer. It happens to other users too.

Comment: If it happens to other users too then it's not about the code. You should contact Discord themselves about the bug: you can do that by going to the "Submit a request" section on the support website ([link](https://support.discordapp.com/hc/en-us/requests/new)).

Answer (score 0):

try this for emojis in order :

```
const emoji = ['1⃣', '2⃣', '3⃣', '4⃣', '5⃣', '6⃣', '7⃣', '8⃣', '9⃣', '']

async function reactEmoji(msg) {
    for (let i = 0; i < emoji.length; i++) {
        let emojiElement = emoji[i]
        await msg.react(emojiElement)
    }
}}

msg.channel
   .send("Your custom message")
   .then(m => reactEmoji(m))
```

Edited

```
msg.react(':raspberrypi:411531368938471425')
```

Comment: Am already doing that, the problem is that it doesn’t work with custom emotes

Comment: Test with that :

`msg.react(':raspberrypi:411531368938471425')`

[See more](https://github.com/thomasbnt/Bord-Pi/blob/master/events/message.js#L17)